# Android if statement is NEVER exectued

Tags: android, if-statement

Please help this is now driving me crazy. 
I have an if, else if and else statement inside a try block.

```
    if (loginSuccess.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        emailAddressEditText.setText("");
                        passwordEditText.setText("");

                        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("redirectURL", redirectUrl);
                        editor.apply();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WebviewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("url", redirectUrl);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (loginSuccess.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ErrorActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("errormessage", "loginerror");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (loginSuccess.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ErrorActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("errormessage", "servererror");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

the first "if" statement never gets executed.
I even tried to create a new String with "true" in it but no success.
Even the log says that the loginSuccess String IS TRUE!

I/System.out: true

What is wrong?

Comment: have you tried debugging? if you debug, stop in that line, read value of "loginSuccess" and add a watcher for your if clause, then check the esit

Comment: yea,tell us where loginSuccess is defined

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
loginSuccess.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("true")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check for null,

```
if(loginSuccess != null)
{
    if(loginSuccess.toString().contains("true"))
     {
      // its true
      // do your code here as required
     }
     else{
     // not contains true
     }
}else
{
 // loginSuccess is null
}
```